# How to convert any type into String in Julia

Tags: julia

Using Julia, I'd like to reliably convert any type into type `String`. There seems to be two ways to do the conversion in v0.5, either the `string` function or `String` constructor. The problem is that you need to choose the right one depending upon the input type.

For example, `typeof(string(1))` evaluates to `String`, but `String(1)` throws an error. On the other hand, `typeof(string(SubString{String}("a")))` evaluates to `Substring{String}`, which is not a subtype of `String`. We instead need to do `String(SubString{String}("a"))`.

So it seems the only reliable way to convert any input `x` to type `String` is via the construct:

```
String(string(x))
```

which feels a bit cumbersome.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why do you need a `String` at the exclusion of all other `AbstractString`s?  Ideally you shouldn't need to care about the exact string type.

Comment: @MattB. No good reason now that you've pointed out that I should be using `AbstractString` in my type definitions... :-)   For the sake of completeness, does this mean that the `String(string(x))` is the most reliable way of getting a `String` type?

Comment: For a reference: now `string(::SubString)` returns a `String`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should rarely need to explicitly convert to `String`. Note that even if your type definitions have `String` fields, or if your arrays have concrete element type `String`, you can still rely on implicit conversion.

For instance, here are examples of implicit conversion:

```
type TestType
    field::String
end

obj = TestType(split("x y")[1])  # construct TestType with a SubString
obj.field  # the String "x"

obj.field = SubString("Hello", 1, 3)  # assign a SubString
obj.field  # the String "Hel"
```

Comment: At least in Julia 1.2.0, this does not seem to hold for situations like ``Foo = Union{Int32,String}``. If you write something with a ``SubString`` in this manner: ``x = substr :: Foo``, you get a typeassert error at run time.

Comment: @BitTickler there is no implicit conversion in the expression `x = substr :: Foo`. However, there is in `a.x = substr` (note there is no typeassert!), where `x` is a string field. As a rule of thumb, `::` does not convert 1) what it is directly attached to in an expression [this is a type-assertion] or 2) the argument it specifies in a function signature [defines dispatch], but it does convert when it defines the a) type of a struct or b) return type of a function. This is initially confusing but I believe these are the only cases to memorize.

Comment: What I mean in my answer is that in most situations, you do not need to worry about explicitly converting to a String, since if you have an object it is often going to be passed into a function, constructor, or struct property, and most functions are defined to dispatch on `AbstractString` (not `String`), and most constructors and struct/array/etc. property assignment will do implicit conversion. The only (rare) context where you would write `x = String(substr)` instead of `x = substr` is if you care that `x` itself is specifically a `String`, e.g. for type stability of a loop variable.