# Converting integer to string in Julia

Tags: string, floating-point, type-conversion, julia

I want to convert an integer to a string in Julia.

When I try:

```
a = 9500
b = convert(String,a)
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type String
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor String(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
 in include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:488
 in process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:265
 in _start() at ./client.jl:321
while loading ..., in expression starting on line 16
```

I am not sure why Int64's cannot be converted to strings.

I have tried defining `a` as different types, for example `a = UInt64(9500)`, but get similar errors.

I know this is very basic and have tried looking for the correct way to do this [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/conversion-and-promotion/#conversion-and-promotion-1), but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: [any use](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Strings_and_characters)?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to convert any type into String in Julia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929009/how-to-convert-any-type-into-string-in-julia). Voting to close.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should use:

```
b = string(a)
```

or

```
b = repr(a)
```

`string` function can be used to create string from any value using `print` and `repr` uses `showall`. In case of `Int64` this is equivalent.

And actually this is probably the reason why convert does not work - as there are many ways to convert integer to string depending on the choice of base.

**EDIT**

For integers you could convert them in the past version of Julia to string also using `bin`, `dec`, `hex`, `oct` or `base`.

Past Julia 1.0 you can do the conversions in different bases using [string](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/strings/#Base.string) function with `base` keyword argument for integers. Also you have `bitstring` function that gives the literal bit representation of a number. Here are some examples:

```
julia> string(100)
"100"

julia> string(100, base=16)
"64"

julia> string(100, base=2)
"1100100"

julia> bitstring(100)
"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001100100"

julia> bitstring(UInt8(100))
"01100100"

julia> string(100.0)
"100.0"

julia> string(100.0, base=2)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching string(::Float64; base=2)
Closest candidates are:
  string(::Any...) at strings/io.jl:156 got unsupported keyword argument "base"
  string(::String) at strings/substring.jl:146 got unsupported keyword argument "base"
  string(::SubString{String}) at strings/substring.jl:147 got unsupported keyword argument "base"
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0

julia> bitstring(100.0)
"0100000001011001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: Small correction: `string` can be used to convert any value to a subtype of `AbstractString`, i.e. the output of `string` is not *always* of type `String`.

Comment: `bin`, `hex`, `base`, etc. were deprecated. The new way to print in a different base is: `string(42, base = 2)`. It also supports padding.